# Orchard CMS display image from MediaPicker using Projector

Tags: orchardcms, projector

I have a content type with a MediaPicker field in it.  The MediaPicker allows the contributor to select an image for the content type.  I'm using Projector to develop a page that renders a list of this content type, but the image doesn't display. I modified the "Rewrite Results" in the layouts for the Projector to write the field to an image: `<img src="{Text}"/>`

But this produces: `<img src="~/Media/.../picture.jpg"/>` and doesn't convert the tilde ~/ to the correct path.

Can you tell me what I'm doing wrong?  What is the best way to render an image using the Projector module?

Thanks!

Comment: How "deep" do you want to go? Are you looking for a solution that uses only the UI? Or is code an option?

Comment: You might want to take a look at: http://orchard.codeplex.com/discussions/347397

Comment: Looks like the following link perhaps satisfies this question:  http://orchard.codeplex.com/discussions/347397  Apparently, the Projector Module **doesn't** currently support displaying MediaPickerField images.  Someone not as green as I will need to step in and offer a solution.  Any takers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I posted on my blog a solution that resolves this issue:

http://coderkelly.wordpress.com/2012/04/18/solved-projector-module-layout-to-display-media-picker-field-as-image/